# ng2-table search not working

Tags: angular, datagrid

I am using [ng2-table]:http://valor-software.com/ng2-table/ with angular2 to display data. It is loading the data but there is a problem with searching.

I have enabled search in the first row of the table.
So when i type something in the search box i need to get column-name and filter-string in the tablechanged event.
But it is giving sorting object.

#### html code:

```
<ng-table (tableChanged)="onChangeTable($event)"[rows]="rows" [columns]="columns">
```

#### typescript code

```
export class test{
 public rows:Array<any> = [];
 public columns:Array<any> = [{title: 'Name', name: 'name', filtering: {filterString: '',placeholder: 'Filter by name'}},{title: 'Salary ($)', name: 'salary', filtering: {filterString: '',placeholder: 'Filter by 'Salary '}}];
 public onChangeTable(filter:any):any{
  alert(filter);
 }
}
```